# How to validate the presence of unwanted character in data field

Tags: unix, error-handling

Using nested for loop How to validate the presence of unwanted characters in each data field depending on data type

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details. Show your (unfinished) code.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.